# Lenovo x240, Ubuntu doesn’t see second laptop battery

Tags: lenovo, battery, thinkpad, 21.10, charging

I have Ubuntu 21.10 on my Lenovo x240. On laptop I have two batteries but Ubuntu don’t see second battery. How can I fix it ?

Comment: if i check correctly i have:
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 21.10
Release: 21.10
Codename: impish

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, 1. you can check BIOS to use both batteries. 2. Normally, two batteries connected in parallel, they work like two reservoirs connected with a canal. Internal battery get drained first, then external one tends to level. Is true in other way, when you charging the internal got full first.